# How to use regex OR in grep in Cygwin?

Tags: regex, cygwin, grep

I need to return results for two different matches from a single file.

```
grep "string1" my.file
```

correctly returns the single instance of string1 in my.file

```
grep "string2" my.file
```

correctly returns the single instance of string2 in my.file

but

```
grep "string1|string2" my.file
```

returns nothing

in regex test apps that syntax is correct, so why does it not work for grep in cygwin ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Using the `|` character without escaping it in a basic regular expression will only match the `|` literal. For instance, if you have a file with contents

```
string1
string2
string1|string2
```

Using `grep "string1|string2" my.file` will only match the last line

```
$ grep "string1|string2" my.file
string1|string2
```

In order to use the alternation operator `|`, you could:

1. Use a basic regular expression (just `grep`) and escape the `|` character in the regular expression

   `grep "string1\|string2" my.file`
2. Use an extended regular expression with `egrep` or `grep -E`, as Julian already pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7874786/851811)

   `grep -E "string1|string2" my.file`
3. If it is two different patterns that you want to match, you could also specify them separately in `-e` options:

   `grep -e "string1" -e "string2" my.file`

You might find the following sections of the `grep` reference useful:

- [Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended)
- [Matching Control](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control), where it explains `-e`

Comment: that works but I expected the sequence to escape the functionality of the pipe rendering it as an ascii pipe character so the regex would be looking for
    "string1|string2"
not doing an or between them

Comment: As @Julian already pointed out, if you're using metacharacters like `|`, `+`, `?`,  and `()` and expect them to work properly without escaping them (as in a normal regexp), you should be using `egrep`. For instance, `egrep "string1|string2"` does the OR. You can still use `grep` if you escape the `|` metacharacter.

Comment: Be careful about `-E`: The OP says _cygwin_, which means that GNU grep is in use. This grep uses extended regexp by default; if you want to have basic regex, you have to request this explicitly (option `-G`).

Answer (score 10):

You may need to either use `egrep` or `grep -E`. The pipe OR symbol is part of 'extended' grep and may not be supported by the basic Cygwin grep.

Also, you probably need to escape the pipe symbol.

Comment: I changed my query to 
    grep -E "string1|string2" my.file
and that correctly matched the two matches
escaping the pipe with -E resulted in no results

Comment: `grep -E` is equivalent to `egrep`; using `egrep` is probably more idiomatic.  In `grep`, `|` is just an ordinary character, and `\|` specifies alternation.  In `egrep`, `|` specifies alternation, and `\|` is just the vertical bar character.

Answer (score 6):

The best and most clear way I've found is:
grep -e *REG1* -e *REG2* -e *REG3* _FILETOGREP_

I never use pipe as it's less evident and very awkward to get working.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this information by reading the fine manual:  grep(1), which you can find by running 'man grep'.  It describes the difference between grep and egrep, and basic and regular expressions, along with a lot of other useful information about grep.

Comment: I'm not sure if your desire is to help the OP or to belittle him. In the case that your desire is to help, providing a relevant link and quote from the manual is far more helpful.

Comment: My intention is to help the OP by teaching him a life skill:  read the manual.  It's plain that he didn't do that.  Post edited to refer him to grep(1).

Comment: I'll remove my downvote in response to your edit. I'm fairly certain that this life skill is better learned with explanation and example than by exhortation.

Answer (score 0):

### `grep -P`

Late to this party, but none of the other answers worked for me. (I was grepping for \d digits.)  This worked:

```
grep -P "string1|string2" my.file
```

From grep --help:

```
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERNS are Perl regular expressions
```